# Compile many SCSS files in one CSS file in PHP

Tags: php, css, sass

I try to compile my SCSS files with the following script:

```
use Leafo\ScssPhp\Compiler;
...
$scss = new Compiler();
$scss->addImportPath('/home/vagrant/Code/myapp/storage/app/scss/');
$cssContent = $scss->compile('@import "style.scss";');
```

The file style.scss has the following content:

```
////
/// Main Stylesheet
/// this file holds includes all files for the stylesheet
////

// a cleaner way to to breakpoints/media queries
// @source
//  http://breakpoint-sass.com/
@import "breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint";


// Helpful mixins
// @source
//  http://bourbon.io/docs/
@import "bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon";

// set default variables
@import "generic/variables/*";
// override default variables and set custom variables
@import "custom/generic/variables/*";

// generic - do not customize this files!
// files are generic and can be updated from base theme
@import "generic/*";
@import "vendor/**/*";
@import "objects/**/*";

// run through stuff in source folders, just patternlab stuff
@import "../source/**/*.scss";

// custom modifications
@import "custom/**/*";
```

The compiled css looks like:

```
@import "breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint";
@import "bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon";
@import "generic/variables/*";
@import "custom/generic/variables/*";
@import "generic/*";
@import "vendor/**/*";
@import "objects/**/*";
@import "../source/**/*.scss";
@import "custom/**/*";
```

So, the compiler compiled only the file style.scss, but did not import any of the files, which should be imported.

I tried to add all the imports manually, like:

```
$cssContent .= $scss->compile('@import "bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon";');
$cssContent .= $scss->compile('@import "generic/variables/*";');
```

But it adds just the following two lines to the CSS code:

```
@import "bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon";
@import "generic/variables/*";
```

Comment: Apaprently your tool does only compile scss to css, you need to then aggregate the generated css files using another tool, personnaly i use gulp for both tasks, but it's with JS not PHP.

Comment: Generally I use also gulp, but in this case I need to compile SASS on a server, where it is not allowed to install gulp...

Comment: Well try to use a tool on top of the one you are using to combine and minify the css generated, I found one called minify, but there are a lot out there : https://github.com/mrclay/minify

Comment: I need to compile SASS. Minify or uglify tools do not help me. I will try: https://github.com/sensational/sassphp

Comment: It's true that the tool I mentioned is called Minify but if you looked at the github page, it says : Minify is an HTTP server for JS and CSS assets. It compresses and combines files and serves it with appropriate headers, allowing conditional GET or long-Expires.

Comment: Antonin, SASS is not meant to be run on a server. You compile it on localhost, then send your SCSS file to the server

Comment: Yes, I know, but I develop a function, which enable to compile SASS for our templates in our internal application and then commit them automatically to GitLab. The aim is to make our development more effective...

Answer (score 0):

> use sccs.inc.php

for More details Visit http://leafo.net/scssphp/